# Unexplained partition gap after Windows installation

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd, disk-management

I used Windows's MediaCreationTool21H2.exe to make a bootable USB flash drive to install Windows 10 on the SSD 2TB of my PC. The installation process starts by asking you which paritition you'd like to install Windows on.

At this point I divided my disk in 2, to install Windows on the first part. The tool asks you the size of the desired partition in "MB". There, I used "1,050,000 MB" as input, without really knowing if it was really MB or MiB...

From this, Windows actually takes some space to create some partitions (in order on the disk) :

- 1 MiB for GPT/MBR
- 100 MiB for System / EFI
- 16 MiB for Microsoft Reserved Partition (MSR) / Hidden
- [Windows Boot Partition / Primary GPT partition]
- 509 MiB for Windows Recovery
- [Unallocated]

I know my input was correctly interpreted as "1,050,000 MiB" which is the total size of the partitions Windows installation has created because : `the 1st sector of the last partition x 512 (sector size) + 509 MiB x 1024^2 = 1,050,000 MiB x 1024^2`

**Now what I don't understand is why I have a "Partition gap" between the end of the Windows Boot Partition and the partition for Windows Recovery?**

[image: WinHex]

It is not really an issue per se given the amount of lost space (714 240 B exactly), but I'd just like to understand :)

I thought may be it was because of some kind of alignment that the end of the Windows 10 partition must respect, but the start of the Windows Recovery partition (1,049,491 MiB exactly) is already a multiple of 512 (sector size), 2048, 4096, 8192, 1 MB, and alignment to 4 MB or 8 MB does not gives the difference I am looking for: 714 240 B = 697.5 KiB ≈ 0,68 MiB. So why Windows discards the space...

FIY: DISKPART and WMIC gives the same numbers than WinHex (except for the total size of disk since some raw space is not usable at its far end because of CHS coordinates limits)

Comment: My guess is the Windows installer does not have a predefined size for the recovery partition (or at least, the predefined size is not an interger in MiB). Then the size of main partition is derived with a formula like [ specified size - 1MiB head - 100MiB ESP - (non-whole-MiB recovery partition + 1MiB extra) ], then the recovery partition is made to start from the next MiB boundary from the end of the main partition til the end of the specified size to use.

Comment: While I attempted to make a deduction, IMHO the question is quite pointless since you won't really get anything out of it. It's like asking why the size of the ESP is an integer in MiB but it's 100MiB instead of 128MiB -- with the answer being Microsoft does not have OCD.

Comment: And in case you are so obsessed that you want to ask: why the size of the recovery partition is not predefined (or another similar question), it's probably because stuff in the recovery partition are relatively (i.e. when compared to those in the ESP) bigger and the size could vary/grow from time to time / depending on circumstances, so Microsoft decided to derive a size upon creation instead of always making it 16GiB or so.

Comment: You say obsession, I'd say curiosity. That's how I discover and learn new things every day. Indeed I wasn't aware that the size of WinRE wasn't fixed, I simply haven't thought of that. Your suggested formula makes sense now I know that. Here, a gap is also mentioned https://www.tenforums.com/backup-restore/143890-windows-re-tools-partition-how-big.html

Comment: might have been an answer instead of a comment. if it wasn't implying I have OCD.

Comment: Nah, i was merely implying that your question might not have existed if Microsoft has OCD (like me). I tend to give comment instead of answer when I don't think it means a lot (like when it isn't precise or the question isn't "general" enough). You can tidy up what you have gathered so far and give an answer yourself -- AFAIK it's welcomed by this site.

Comment: @hymced To clarify, did you create the 1.05TB partition within Setup's GUI or `DiskPart`, how many MBs did you leave in front of it when you created the partition, and did you manually create and partitions other than the OS partition?

Comment: Setup's GUI, I only created that one partition, the rest was left before Installation (and still is) unallocated. The Setup doesn't allow to use an offset

Comment: @hymced So when you created the OS partition in Setup, there were only two things listed under the disk, a `1050000` partition and unallocated space after _(I want to try and recreate the issue)_? The offset is created automatically by Setup when the first partition is created during the `windowsPE` configuration pass _(Windows is installed over four configuration passes [`windowsPE`, `offlineServicing`, `specialize`, `oobeSystem`] - there are seven total with `generalize`, but unless you customize the install with an answer file, it, `auditSystem`, and `auditUser` are skipped)_

Comment: yes I think so, I discovered the other partitions only when Windows actually started. I am not familiar with the configuration passes

Comment: @hymced Does `DiskMgmt.msc` show the unallocated 698KB? _(If not, you may want to open a bug report with Microsoft, as I've been unable to replicate and can find no other instances of this occurring using multiple search engines, or by searching Microsoft Docs.)_

Answer (score -1):

*(I can't answer the primary question of the odd 698KB unallocated space between the OS and WinRE partitions, as I'm unable to replicate the issue)*

---

> From this, Windows actually takes some space to create some partitions (in order on the disk) :
>
> - 1 MiB for GPT/MBR
> - 100 MiB for System / EFI
> - 16 MiB for Microsoft Reserved Partition (MSR) / Hidden
> - [Windows Boot Partition / Primary GPT partition]
> - 509 MiB for Windows Recovery
> - [Unallocated]

- The 1MB space at the front of the drive occurs because the first partition [ESP] is aligned at 1024KB, created during Setup's [`windowsPE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windowspe) configuration pass with [`DiskPart`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/create-partition-efi) command:

  ```cmd
  cre par efi offset=1024
  ```
- The Windows boot partition is the EFI [UEFI] or System (`active`) [BIOS] partition - a `%SystemDrive%` cannot be [booted](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/img-boot-sequence) without the boot files on the EFI/System partition

  - While `C:` can be used as a boot drive in BIOS *(not recommended)*, it cannot be used with UEFI because it requires partition [GUID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/guid-partitioning-table-disk-faq#extensible-firmware-interface-system-partition) `c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b`, whereas basic data partitions like `C:` have [GUID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/guid-partitioning-table-disk-faq#how-is-a-basic-data-partition-identified) `ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7`
- The WinRE partition size cannot be predetermined unless the specific size of the `Winre.wim` for the specific version of Windows being installed is known, as the WIM [**W**indows **IM**age] for WinRE does grow with new OS versions and should have ~300MB of free space to absorb future increases in the WIM size *(for current Windows versions, the `Winre.wim` is ~400MB)*

  1. To determine the size of the `Winre.wim`, mount the `install.wim` || `install.esd`: 
     <sup>*(Open terminal via `Shift`+`F10`)*</sup>

     ```cmd
     ::# Get drive letter of Windows Install USB and partition to mount image on:
         Diskpart
           Lis Vol
           Exit

     ::# Get index for the OS version being installed from Install USB's install.wim || install.esd:
         Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"Z:\sources\install.wim"

     ::# Create mount folder on a partition other than X:
         MkDir "Z:\Mount"

     ::# Mount index of the OS being installed from the install.wim || install.esd:
         Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\source\install.wim" /Index:6 /MountDir:"Z:\Mount" /ReadOnly
     ```
  2. Get `Winre.wim` size:

     ```cmd
     Dir "Z:\Mount\Windows\System32\Recovery"

     ::# If Winre.wim not found:
         Dir /A:sh "Z:\Mount\Windows\System32\Recovery"
     ```
  3. Unmount `install.wim` || `install.esd`:

     ```cmd
     Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:"Z:\Mount" /Discard
     ```

---

To avoid this in the future when not using the full drive for `C:`, I always recommend manually configuring the partitions in `DiskPart` within Setup, before selecting what partition to install to, by opening a terminal via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>:

1. **Select installation drive:** 
    <sup>*(assumes data isn't being preserved, as `clean` wipes the partition table)*</sup>

   ```cmd
   DiskPart

   Lis Dis
   Sel Dis #
   Clean
   ```

   **UEFI:**

   ```cmd
   Convert Gpt
   ```
2. **Create boot partition:**

   - **[BIOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions):**

     ```cmd
     Cre Par Pri Size=100 Offset=1024
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=Boot
     Active
     ```
   - **[UEFI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions):**

     ```cmd
     Cre Par EFI Size=100 Offset=1024
     Format Quick Fs=FAT32 Label=EFI
     Cre Par Msr Size=16
     ```
3. **Create OS partition:** 
    <sup>*(Multiply size wanted by 1024: `300*1024=307200`)*</sup>

   - **BIOS:**

     ```cmd
     ::# if storing User Data directories on a partition other than C: (recommended), max size required is ~300GB
         Cre Par Pri Size=307200
         Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
     ```
   - **UEFI:**

     ```cmd
     ::# if storing User Data directories on a partition other than C: (recommended), max size required is ~300GB
         Cre Par Pri Size=307200 Id=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
         Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
     ```
4. **Create WinRE partition:** *([defaulted](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#recovery-tools-partition) to after the OS partition in [v2004](https://www.windowslatest.com/2020/07/12/windows-10-windows-setup-recovery-partition/))* 
    <sup>*(should have 300MB free - `WinRE.wim` is currently ~400MB in size)*</sup>

   - **BIOS:**

     ```cmd
     Cre Par Pri Offset=1024 Size=750 Id=27
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=WinRE
     Exit
     ```
   - **UEFI:**

     ```cmd
     Cre Par Pri Offset=1024 Size=750 Id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=WinRE
     Gpt Attributes=0x8000000000000001
     Exit
     ```
5. **Close terminal and continue in Setup as normal**

   - *Partitions need to be created before Setup asks which partition to install too, otherwise Setup needs to be refreshed by going back a step in the Setup GUI, then forward again*

Comment: Thank you for all theses details. Can you explain your bullet point about the RAW partition? what is it? how does it come into play with the gap? how did you estimate its size?

Comment: About the WinRE partition, why the 1024 KB offset? Could it just not start on the end boundary of the previous partition?

Comment: For the OS Partition, where does the 300GB limitation comes from? In my cas its way more? Why? I might install several 50GB+ games.

Comment: @hymced Apparently he derived this "RAW size" (which makes no sense at all) with `1050000 * 1024 / 1000`. Let alone the fact that the formula is wrong (because 1050000 is in MiB but not KiB), I don't recall (recent) Windows actually shows/takes value in SI unit anywhere. What it does is that it calls/labels the values in binary units without the `i` (in other words, all the K/M/G...(B) you see/input in Windows are / will be treated as Ki/Mi/Gi...B). diskpart, PS-cmdlets, Disk Management, Windows Setup...same story for all of them.

Comment: @hymced Offsetting the first partition by 1024KB [1MB] is sane partitioning, something Microsoft borrowed from Linux a few years back _(this previously wasn't the default in Win <10)_. The max required OS partition size is ~300GB because if User Data [`%UserProfile%\Documents`, `Downloads`, etc.] is stored on a partition other than `C:` via each folder's properties' _Location_ tab, it's highly unlikely 270GB will be exceeded by installed software _(at least 10% of `C:` should always be free)_. For games, consider storing them on a dedicated partition initially/via a junction link [`MkLink /j`]

Comment: About your last comment, this is user dependent and irrelevant to my question, there is no real "max required sized". About the previous comment, I ask why there is a gap of ~0,68 MiB, and you reply explains how to partition with a 1 MiB offset because you think it is "same partitioning". About your first 2 comments, I never mentioned the size displayed in Windows Explorer, I think you confuse logical disk size (volume) and partition size, or you refer to volume slack maybe.

Comment: @hymced You asked several questions in comments, which I answered. As I stated in the answer "_...this is the only reason that makes sense with the provided information.._" - if you disagree with that logical reasoning, it's easy to find out whether or not what I posit is correct. As to a 1MB offset being sane partitioning, please Google it for a better understanding, as it's covered extensively for BSD and Linux and is something Microsoft borrowed from unix OSes with Windows 10.

Comment: @JW0914 you misunderstand me, I never said what you post was wrong, I have learned things, but it is not answering my question

Comment: @hymced I apologize, as I realize after re-reviewing your screenshot and question's content, I've been looking at this from the wrong perspective. I'll do some more research and update the answer accordingly, and if I can't find why this occurs, I'll remove a significant portion of the answer because it doesn't address your primary question.

Comment: @JW0914 haha alright but in a way your reply as good info even if it doesn't immediately address my question. If I get it right, and if that gap is not absolutely necessary, I could prepare the ground and the partitions (without the gap) before launching Setup, and then Windows Installation would use the partitions and not overwrite them, correct?

Comment: or rather delete them and then recreate them with a gap

Comment: @hymced You can safely remove the KBs worth of unallocated space by extending the OS or WinRE partition to encapsulate it

Comment: @hymced I'm unable to replicate the issue, so I've updated the answer to reflect this and added some contextualized information

Comment: @JW0914 thanks I will give it another try from a fresh unallocated disk soon